# pythonanywhere не дает установить библиотеку

Tags: telegram-bot, pythonanywhere

Пытаюсь разместить бота на сервере pythonanywhere, чтобы тот работал, мне нужно установить несколько библиотек. Ошибка возникла только при установке 'types'
Сама ошибка:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement types (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for types

Чтобы установить библиотеку, писал в консоли 'pip3 install --user types'. Не вышло)

Если кто-нибудь знает, как это исправить, помогите)

Comment: Зачем её устанавливать, она встроена в питон

Answer (score 1):

Types - стандартная библиотека, и в pythonanywhere она тоже есть, так что можете её просто импортировать и использовать.

Comment: Выдает такую ошибку при запуске бота. Я думал, что это связанно с тем, что этой библиотеки нет, извините. Не знаете, что сделать, чтобы бот начал работать? Припуске пишет: "from telebot import types
ImportError: cannot import name 'types' from 'telebot'"

Answer (score 0):

в `pythonanywhere` запрещены некоторые библиотеки в бесплатном плане. одна из них - `telegrambotapi`. из-за этого не будет работать ни одна библиотека для создания ботов телеграм. они просто не установятся